# Static Reference (function?) to a db in SQL 2005 & 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

We are in desperate need to having some way to reference a static table in SQL. I'm assuming this maybe possible using a function but i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

For example I want to ...

-on SQL Server A (2005)

```
SELECT * FROM staticDB.someTbl
```

-on SQL Server B (2008)

```
SELECT * FROM staticDB.someTbl
```

then on each server have the real "staticDB" reference someplace

Hopefully this makes sense!

Thanks

*EDIT*
So when I have a stored procedure  on our dev server it points to the dev db (via the function/var). Then on the prd server it points to prd db. Instead of having to remember to replace them every time. We can have one reference to this function/var and it would just work across both servers.

Something like a connection string equivalent, but for SQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should just replicate `staticDB` across the different servers.

Comment: Have a look at SYNONYMS and LINKED SERVERS

Comment: We have linked servers, i'm not sure what Synonyms are... The servers are linked. I'm trying to store the "staticDB" in some type of function or variable somehow. So when I have a stored procedure  on our dev server it points to the dev db (via the function/var). Then on the prd server it points to prd. Instead of having to remember to replace them every time. We can have one reference to this function/var and it would just work across both servers. 

Something like a connection string equivalent, but for SQL.

Comment: @MarkD -- i think Synonyms sound perfect. Sounds so easy not sure why this wasn't done along time ago!!!

Comment: @MarkD - do SYNONYMS have to reference a table? If so this may not work as we would need to create a synonyms for 1000+ tbls, one for each environement (prd &dev). Ideally I just want something to reference the linked database, and I could still define the tbl in the t-sql

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I can help with that

Comment: @MarkD - We ended up going with the Synonyms and created a script to generate the synonyms for the 1000+ tables we have in our ERP. If you can answer the question Mark and i'll mark it!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the offer - but I just pointed you in the direction I think you should go :)